# Magnetic field of a current carrying wire reduce/increase exterior magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics

If we place a wire within a uniform exterior magnetic field ($B_x$) that's perpendicular to it's length, and allowed current to flow withing the that conductive medium, there is another magnetic field generated from that wire ($B_w$). There is a Lorentz force as well, **however**, due to the $B_w$ existing with $B_x$ would they add or subtract from the net strength of each field?

Diagram:

[image]

The orange lines is of the exterior magnetic field, wanted to illustrate it in the most important views(right & top).

As a result of the magnetic field, there is a Lorentz force, would $B$ in the formula be only $B_x$? Why wouldn't it be ($B_x$ - $B_s$) or ($B_x$ + $B_s$)?
Likewise, if the wire was able to accelerate in the the magnetic field, the induced motional EMF's $B$ be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B should remain since Magnetic
field is added in upper part and equally
subtracted in lower part.

Hint: Wire does not experience its own magnetic force.

If you let wire to accelerate in $B$ freely , it won't give any magnetic field.. So, no current flow in wire. Hence EMF is induced in opposite direction.

Comment: I've adjusted the diagram, also,the magnetic field is uniform. I don't understand how and why it would be added in the upper part and subtracted in the lower part equally? Shouldn't they be the same at all points?

Comment: In upper part both magnetic field are towards right. So, they are added. In lower part they are opposite in direction, so are subtracted.